# It does't moves properly all faces

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, transforms, faces

I have problem with moving faces I have done faces for medallion and wanted to move all faces down. I tried to extrude and then move, but it's not working. Do you know what is wrong with mine model? Also, I tried to look if there aren't doubled vertices somewhere, but there aren't.

[image]

If I'll delete faces there wouldn't be for the eye and other details.

[image]

My file is [here](https://pasteall.org/blend/3b0b0ef859b542f184ebba856176d1d0)

Comment: hello could you please share your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi @moonboots, I don't if I did it right, but https://pasteall.org/blend/3b0b0ef859b542f184ebba856176d1d0

Comment: so when you say that you extrude, move and it doesn't work, could you please be more precise? What do you try to extrude, move, and in what way it doesn't work?

Comment: Okay, so I mark all faces (head of the wolf), then I press E and try to move down, then it would be like this https://pasteboard.co/y52KMmfqBTqi.png and then I should delete faces.

Comment: @moonboots, I think that the extruding isn't the right way, but I don't how to do it properly

Comment: I try to understand what you're trying to do  ^^  I hope someone will do better than me

Comment: @moonboots, If it helps I'm trying to have "doubled" all faces and then delete the down faces and the result should look like this https://pasteboard.co/8xM5iZvr5r2m.png , but I was thinking about it right now and got an idea to extrude up and not down

Comment: I think if you extrude in vertex mode instead of face mode it should work properly